# How to play an attachment video from the timeline item

Tags: google-mirror-api

I want to insert a timelineitem with video attachment and if user selects a specific menu item, glass to play the video. I'm doing all from .net app like this, please correct me, if i'm doing wrong.

```
TimelineItem item = new TimelineItem()
    item.MenuItems.Insert(0, new MenuItem(){Action="what is the action to use?";...});
    request = Service.Timeline.Insert(item, attachment, contentType);
    request.Upload();
```

I would like to know, do i need a menu item, if yes, what is the action i should use?
Currently i'm sending the video attachment, but there is no way to play the video.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to specify any `menuItems` but your timeline item should not contain `html` content.

Make sure that your video is of a [supported format](https://developers.google.com/glass/ui-guidelines#quick_reference): once it's inserted, and Glass has synced and fully downloaded the attached video, it should start playing right when you land on the item in your timeline.

Comment: I'm sending text timeline item with video attachment(7 sec/2MB). Video Codec: H.264/MPEG-4 AVC, Video Size: 640x360, Frame Rate: 29.97fps, Aspect Ratio: 16:9, Audio Codec is: MPEG-4 AAC. Timelineitem comes but i don't see any video playback. I tried various video codecs. Nothing works, is there a sample video that i can try?

Comment: I was passing attachment ContentType as "video/*", when i changed to "video/mp4", it worked fine, you have to be patient, there is a latency. I don't want to resend the same video, is there a way of bundling timeline item with previously send timeline item, so that it can be played without any delay.

Comment: You can bump a previously sent timeline item closer to the clock by either updating its `displayTime` or `updated` time. Bundling is done by simply setting the same `bundleId` in a set of timeline item. Please note that timeline items stay in Glass for up to a week and up to a month in the API (this can change).

Comment: Video is working now, but the way i want is different. I want to send a status notification to user about some resource is gone bad, if user wants to fix the issue, he will select an option which will play the video helping him to fix the issue. Send a bundled timelineitem, first timelineitem is text message, second timelineitem with video attachment which will be played once he select the timeline item menu option <play>

Comment: You can send both items as a bundle as you already mentioned, this is actually what the CNN Glassware does. To add the menuItem functionality, you would need to file a feature request in our [issues tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/list) as it is not yet supported by the Glass client nor the API.

Answer (score 1):

This works using the QuickStart project for Java (mirror-java-starter-demo):

https://github.com/googleglass/mirror-quickstart-java

Replace the lines near line 119 in MainServlet.java with this:

```
URL url = new URL(req.getParameter("imageUrl"));
String contentType = req.getParameter("contentType");
url = new URL("http://localhost:8888/static/videos/video.mp4");
contentType = "video/mp4"; 
byte[] b = ByteStreams.toByteArray(url.openStream());
int i = b.length;
InputStream temp = url.openStream();
MirrorClient.insertTimelineItem(credential, timelineItem, contentType, temp);
```

Then run the project and click the "A Picture" button to upload a video from a new folder inside static called videos called video.mp4.  I used a 10 second clip I recorded with glass (6.30 MB).

Note that when running with App Engine 1.76 on a windows machine I got this error when uploading, but changing to 1.80 made this issue go away:

[image]

Here is Windows metadata about the video that might be useful:

[image]

Depending on your network connection it might take a little bit for the video to show in your timeline, but mine plays.

Comment: I have forked the mirror-java-starter demo project to include the ability to add a video to the timeline as an attachment, including video of Sweetie, the cat.  I will make a pull request, but in the meantime you can get it here: https://github.com/mscheel/mirror-quickstart-java